# Given an array, replace each prime number with the next prime number

Tags: ruby

So 
`#[11,13,17,23] => [13,17,19,29]`

if the number isn't prime, then the function is just returning the number
`#[11,8,2,24] => [13,8,3,24]`

I'm having so much trouble with the very last number (29), for some reason, it's going into an infinite loop. I feel like there is such a simple solution, but it's just escaping me..

```
def next_prime(arr)
  new_arr = []
  arr.each do |num|
    #puts num
    if prime?(num)
      p = false
      i = num + 2
      while !p
        p = prime?(i)
        i += 2
      end
      new_arr << i
    else
      new_arr << num
    end
  end
  new_arr
end
```

EDIT: here is the prime function

```
def prime?(num)
  if num ==1
    return false
  elsif num < 3
    return true
  elsif num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0
    return false
  end


  i = 5
  while i*i <= num
    if num % i == 0 || num % (i + 2) == 0
      return false
    end
    i += 6
  end
  return true
end
```

Comment: can you please post the prime function? Maybe that's returning false for 29.

Comment: I added the prime function above and also confirmed when calling it that 29 is prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first array works decently for me, even the `29`, except for the fact that everything is 2 higher than it should be, because you add 2 after you check if you have a prime which can be fixed by a slight alteration to the code:

```
if prime?(num)
  p = false
  i = num
  while !p
    i += 2

    p = prime?(i)
  end
  new_arr << i
```

The only infinite loop I encounter is when you hit `2` in the second array, because to check for primes, you just keep incrementing by 2, and so you end up checking every multiple of 2 to see if it's prime. Naturally you never find a prime multiple of 2. To fix this, instead of incrementing by 2 before checking for the next prime, if you increment by 1 would work, you just need to check twice as many numbers:

```
if prime?(num)
  p = false
  i = num
  while !p
    i += 1

    p = prime?(i)
  end
  new_arr << i
```

your last problem is that your `prime?` function returns `false` for 3, which can be fixed by changing:

```
elsif num <= 3
  return true
```

and now your 2 samples yield:

```
[11, 13, 17, 23] => [13, 17, 19, 29]
[11, 8, 2, 24] => [13, 8, 3, 24]
```

Comment: Stupid simple. I just needed another set of eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed the array `arr` is sorted. If it isn't, save the original indices of the sorted values, which are then used  to reorder the elements of the array of values containing prime and non-prime numbers. For example, if

```
arr = [57, 13, 28, 6]
```

then

```
indices = arr.each_with_index.sort.map(&:last)
  #=> [3, 1, 2 0]
```

The steps of the the main method are as follows.

- Step 1: create an empty array `a` that will be returned by the method.
- Step 2: create an enumerator, `enum`, that generates an infinite sequence of prime numbers (2, 3, 5, 7,..). Generate the first prime `m = enum.next #=> 2`.
- Step 3: create an enumerator, `earr`, that generate the elements of the given array `arr`.
- Step 4: consider the next element of the array, `x = earr.next`, which is initially the first element of the array. When there are no more elements of the array, break from the loop and return the array `a`.
- Step 5: if `x` is not prime save it to an array `a` (`a << x`) and repeat step 4; else go to Step 6.
- Step 6: (`x` is prime) if `x < m`, save `m` to the array `a` and go to 
  Step 4; else (i.e., `m <= x`), obtain the next prime (`m = enum.next`) and repeat this step.

```
require 'prime"

def next_primes(arr)
  enum = Prime.each
  m = enum.next    
  earr = arr.to_enum
  x = earr.next
  a = []
  loop do
    if x.prime?
      if x < m
        a << m
        x = earr.next 
      else
        m = enum.next
      end 
    else
      a << x
      x = earr.next
    end
  end
  a
end

next_primes([2, 6, 7, 23, 100])
  #=> [3, 6, 11, 29, 100]
next_primes([2, 6, 7, 7, 100])
  #=> [3, 6, 11, 11, 100]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, the problem specifically stated I can't use Prime or any prime number generator :)

Comment: I don't see where you said that in the question. In any event I believe there is merit in my approach, for reasons of efficiency. All one needs to do is implement the methods `Integer#prime?` (straightforward) and an enumerator that generates primes (Sieve of  Eratosthenes). The alternative is to check numbers following a prime until one is found that is prime, which would be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) answer, but more idiomatic Ruby IMHO.

```
require 'prime'

def next_primes(ary)
  ary.map { |candidate| candidate.prime? ? next_prime(candidate) : candidate }
end

def next_prime(previous_prime)
  all_primes = Prime.each
  all_primes.find { |prime| prime > previous_prime }
end                            

next_primes([11,8,2,24]) # => [13, 8, 3, 24]
next_primes([11,13,17,23]) # => [13, 17, 19, 29]
```

Comment: A weakness is that each time `next_prime` is called in starts at  `2` when searching for a prime that satisfies the requirement. It's more efficient to step through the enumerator just once.

Comment: Agree, but when it's possible I always prefer readability over efficiency :)

Comment: I like the brevity of this solution. To make it more efficient, you could memoize the results.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to find the next prime number if it is a prime number if not return the same number:

```
def is_prime(num)
    if num<2
      return false
    end
    (2...num).each do |i|
      if num%i == 0
        return false
      end
    end
    return true

  end

def next_prime(arr)
    new_arr = []
    arr.each do |num|
        if is_prime(num)
            p = false
            i = num
            while !p
                i += 1
                p = is_prime(i)
            end
            new_arr<<i
        else
            new_arr<<num
        end
    end
    return new_arr

end
print next_prime([2,3,4,5])
puts

print next_prime([2, 6, 7, 23, 100]) #[3, 6, 11, 29, 100]
```